# Как избежать округления чисел?

Tags: c++

У Unita есть:

```
float hp = 100.0
```

и Wolf:

```
float hp = 200.0
```

Unit когда превращается в Wolf то его хп должно соответствовать Хп волку только с учетом того что у Unita уже не полное хп

```
changeState() {
   unit->setHp(wolf->getHp()/100*200);
}
```

при делении Unit->хп округляется до нуля, как это исправить, что бы было число с запятой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее вероятная проблема в том, что `getHp()` возвращает целое число, и далее получается целочисленное деление, которое по определению же дает целочисленный результат. Например `10/100` даст `0`, а не `0.1`. Чтобы результат был вещественным достаточно хотя бы один из аргументов тоже сделать вещественного типа. В Вашем случае можно написать так:

```
wolf->getHp()/100.0*200 // добавили .0
```

Или сделать возвращаемый `getHp()` тип вещественным.

Comment: 100.0 - это double, у автора данные во float - зачем лишнее преобразование?
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/

Comment: @gbg в общем согласен. Однако само использование типа `float` вместо `double` должно быть обусловлено чем-то более серьёзным, чего ТС, скорее всего, ещё не понимает. В данном вопросе основной момент всё же кроется в различии целый/не целый, а не в `double`/`float`.

Answer (score 1):

Не делить на целое число. Делить на `float`.

```
unit->setHp(wolf->getHp()/100.0f*200.0f);
```

С точки зрения С++, `100` - это `int`. У вас все приводится к `int`, что выглядит как округление.

А `100.0f` - `float`. Как раз то, что нужно.